# Discrepancy Between Bode Plot Predictions and FFT Output for Higher-Order Low Pass Filters on a 10 kHz Square Wave

Tags: filter, ltspice, bode-plot, fft

I have conducted an experiment where a 10 kHz square wave is input through low pass filters of 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th orders. After passing the square wave through these filters, I observed the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) output for each filter. Surprisingly, the FFT analysis indicates that each filtered output exhibits a -20 dB/decade slope, which is characteristic of a 1st order filter, regardless of the filter order. This is despite the Bode plots for these filters showing the expected -20 dB/decade slope per order of magnitude in frequency (i.e., -20 dB/decade for the 1st order, -40 dB/decade for the 2nd order, and so on). Given that the Bode plots confirm the correct frequency responses for each filter, what could be causing the FFT output to reflect a -20 dB/decade slope across all filter orders?

[image: Bode plot showing the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th order filter at cut off frequency of 1kHz]
[image: Impulse response of the filters with a 10Khz 50% duty cycle square wave]
[image: Test circuit]
[image: FFT of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th order Low pass filter]

EDIT:
Taking FFT between 2msec and 3msec to avoid transient related problems with circuit initialization. The noise floor for 1st and 2nd order LP filter is almost flat upto 200kHz. May be this norise floor is not affected by the order of the filter.

[image: FFT between 2msec and 3msec]

LTSpice Code:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2444 680
WIRE 2336 -512 2128 -512
WIRE 1856 -496 1648 -496
WIRE 992 -480 816 -480
WIRE 1376 -480 1168 -480
WIRE 2128 -416 2128 -512
WIRE 2176 -416 2128 -416
WIRE 1648 -400 1648 -496
WIRE 1696 -400 1648 -400
WIRE 2336 -400 2336 -512
WIRE 2336 -400 2240 -400
WIRE 2368 -400 2336 -400
WIRE 1168 -384 1168 -480
WIRE 1216 -384 1168 -384
WIRE 1856 -384 1856 -496
WIRE 1856 -384 1760 -384
WIRE 1888 -384 1856 -384
WIRE 2000 -384 1888 -384
WIRE 2112 -384 2080 -384
WIRE 2176 -384 2112 -384
WIRE 816 -368 816 -480
WIRE 864 -368 816 -368
WIRE 1376 -368 1376 -480
WIRE 1376 -368 1280 -368
WIRE 1408 -368 1376 -368
WIRE 1520 -368 1408 -368
WIRE 1632 -368 1600 -368
WIRE 1696 -368 1632 -368
WIRE 992 -352 992 -480
WIRE 992 -352 928 -352
WIRE 1040 -352 992 -352
WIRE 1152 -352 1120 -352
WIRE 1216 -352 1152 -352
WIRE 640 -336 608 -336
WIRE 752 -336 720 -336
WIRE 864 -336 752 -336
WIRE 2112 -336 2112 -384
WIRE 1632 -320 1632 -368
WIRE 1152 -304 1152 -352
WIRE 752 -288 752 -336
WIRE 2112 -256 2112 -272
WIRE 1632 -240 1632 -256
WIRE 1152 -224 1152 -240
WIRE 752 -208 752 -224
WIRE -32 112 -32 64
WIRE 64 112 64 64
WIRE -32 240 -32 192
WIRE 64 240 64 192
FLAG -32 240 0
FLAG 64 240 0
FLAG -32 64 vcc
FLAG 64 64 vnn
FLAG 608 -336 pulse_in
FLAG 752 -208 0
FLAG 1152 -224 0
FLAG 1408 -368 2
FLAG 272 -16 0
FLAG 272 -96 sine_in
FLAG 896 -384 vcc
FLAG 896 -320 vnn
FLAG 1248 -400 vcc
FLAG 1248 -336 vnn
FLAG 992 -352 1
FLAG 1632 -240 0
FLAG 1888 -384 3
FLAG 1728 -416 vcc
FLAG 1728 -352 vnn
FLAG 2112 -256 0
FLAG 2368 -400 4
FLAG 2208 -432 vcc
FLAG 2208 -368 vnn
FLAG 432 -16 0
FLAG 432 -96 pulse_in
SYMBOL voltage -32 96 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 15
SYMBOL voltage 64 96 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value -15
SYMBOL res 736 -352 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 736 -288 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value {C}
SYMBOL res 1136 -368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 1136 -304 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value {C}
SYMBOL voltage 272 -112 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpAmp 896 -352 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpAmp 1248 -368 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL res 1616 -384 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 1616 -320 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value {C}
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpAmp 1728 -384 R0
SYMATTR InstName U3
SYMBOL res 2096 -400 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 2096 -336 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value {C}
SYMBOL Opamps\\UniversalOpAmp 2208 -400 R0
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMBOL voltage 432 -112 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 3 24 154 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 0 1p 1p 50u 100u 100)
TEXT -296 -208 Left 2 !;.ac dec 10 10 1Meg\n.tran 3m
TEXT 408 -664 Left 2 ;fc = 1Khz\nw = 6283
TEXT 400 -520 Left 2 !.param w=6283\n.param RC=1/{w}\n.param R=10K\n.param C=RC/{R}
```

Comment: The FFT looks right to me. Maybe you are concerned about the general slope (inapplicable)?

Comment: @Andyaka, what do you mean the general slope is inapplicable?

Comment: I mean what I said; it is a falsehood; an artefact of your measurement method. You can still clearly see the harmonic peaks attenuating much faster as you go higher in frequency.

Comment: Now you have the noise floor down where it belongs, you can see that the signal harmonics are decreasing at the rate you would expect from the filters. The noise floor is the result of limited dynamic of the numbers you're using, any residual transient in the data, not a result of the filter input or output signals themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Three of your plots have a 20dB/decade slope of the baseline, the three that went through your filter simulation. This baseline is obscuring what's happening to the harmonics, that will actually be dropping at the expected rate.

This slope is characteristic of there being a step response within the data. I suspect that you have taken data right from the startup of the simulation, without waiting for the startup transient to die away. This transient would be caused by the filter capacitors not having the initial charge that they eventually end up with.

There are two possible fixes for this. One is to run the simulation until the DC output has settled down, and only then start taking output data. The other is to use initial conditions to set the initial capacitor voltages up so there is no initial transient, which can be quite tricky but is do-able.

Comment: I took your advice and took FFT only between 2msec and 3msec.  The noise floors from each LP output look almost flat. I suppose this noise floor is the limitation of the system itself, and has nothing to do with the order of the filters.